# Geshi does not detect libraries on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I have installed the Geshi Filter and Field modules, but Drupal does not detect the GeShi Libraries.

1. I got the Geshi Libraries from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geshi/files/geshi-dev/GeSHi%201.1.2alpha3/GeSHi-1.1.2-alpha3.zip/download). To be sure, I put it in: 
   `/sites/all/libraries/` ,  `/sites/all/modules/libraries/` and `/sites/all/modules/geshifilter/`
2. I am using 7.x-1.x-dev

[image]

Yet, it cannot find the libraries. How can I get it to work? Please do not suggest syntaxhighlighter. I have tried it and I would prefer a server side solution.

From the Status Report[image]

Answer (score 1):

The files should be copied, for example, in "sites/all/libraries/geshi" or "$config/libraries/geshi," where "$config" is the directory containing the settings.php file used for the Drupal site.
In the first case, the class.geshi.php file is put in "sites/all/libraries/geshi/class.geshi.php," and the "geshi" directory that is in the downloaded archive is put in "sites/all/libraries/geshi/geshi."

As for where the Libraries API module looks for the directory containing the library files, the documentation comment for `libraries_get_libraries()` reports the following text:

> Returns an array of library directories from the all-sites directory (i.e. sites/all/libraries/), the profiles directory, and site-specific directory (i.e. sites/somesite/libraries/).

The site-specific directory is the one that I reported as "$config/libraries/geshi."
The module doesn't look in "sites/all/modules/libraries."

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in this [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/1148540), flushing all caches once or twice will resolve the issue. Worked on my end after one flush.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing cache didn't work for me -- but flushing all caches then turning off the geshifilter module, and reenabling it -- that worked.

Answer (score 0):

On the module home page, it clearly says:

> #### Important Note
>
> only the 1.0.x branch of the GeSHi library is supported, so **do not
> use the development branch GeSHi 1.1.x**. Direct link to GeSHi 1.0.x
> releases: http://sourceforge.net/projects/geshi/files/geshi/

The source forge link you provided downloads **GeSHi-1.1**.2-alpha3.zip which you are not suppose to use.